# Are we allowed to call pthread_key_create and pthread_key_delete from different threads? Should lmdb make this clear?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, posix, lmdb

### Details about the issue leading to the question

We're facing a SIGSEGV error under extremely rare circumstances when using the lmdb database library that are not easily reproducible. The best we got out of it is a stack-trace that looks like this through the core dump:

```
#0 in mdb_env_reader_dest (ptr=...) at .../mdb.c: 4935
#1 in __nptl_deallocate_tsd () at pthread_create.c:301
...
```

The line the stack-trace is pointing to [is this](https://github.com/LMDB/lmdb/blob/b53474758f4fbcca2e76031017bbddfe92474e30/libraries/liblmdb/mdb.c#L5042) (it's not the same because we attempted some changes to fix this).

Having tracked the issue for a while, the only explanation I have is that, when closing the lmdb environment from a thread other than the main thread, there's some kind of race between  [this line](https://github.com/LMDB/lmdb/blob/b53474758f4fbcca2e76031017bbddfe92474e30/libraries/liblmdb/mdb.c#L5820) and [this line](https://github.com/LMDB/lmdb/blob/b53474758f4fbcca2e76031017bbddfe92474e30/libraries/liblmdb/mdb.c#L5730), where the latter deletes the key, calls the custom destructor `mdb_env_reader_dest`, which [causes SIGSEGV according to the documentation of lmdb, when attempting to use resources after freeing them](http://www.lmdb.tech/doc/group__internal.html#ga841fffbcc4b42bb6ae9710201f9f31ab).

### The question

The documentation of `pthread_key_create` and `pthread_key_delete` are ambiguous to me, personally, in the sense whether they're talking about the calls to `pthread_key_create` and `pthread_key_delete` or the data underneath the pointers. This is [what the docs say](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_key_delete):

> The associated destructor functions used to free thread-specific data at thread exit time are only guaranteed to work correctly when called in the thread that allocated the thread-specific data.

So the question is, can we call `mdb_env_open` and `mdb_env_close` from two different threads, leading to `pthread_key_create` and `pthread_key_delete` from different threads, and expect correct behavior?

I couldn't find such a requirement in the lmdb documentation. The closest I could find [is this](http://www.lmdb.tech/doc/group__internal.html#ga841fffbcc4b42bb6ae9710201f9f31ab), which doesn't seem to reference the `mdb_env_open` function.

Comment: This is not the question you asked, but looking at `mdb_env_reader_dest()` and the stack trace, the function is apparently a TSD destructor function, being called at the termination of a thread.  A segfault at the specific line you call out indicates that that thread's TSD pointer for the associated key is non-NULL but invalid.  This will most likely have arisen because it once was a valid pointer, but the object it points to was freed.  I can imagine that situation arising as a result of `mdb_env_close` being called in the thread, though I would also characterize that as an LMDB bug.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I agree with you 100%, and in fact, your analysis is exactly my analysis for the situation... I'm just trying to find whether we broke any POSIX rules. What you're imagining, that this could have come from `mdb_env_close` being called in another thread, is the only viable explanation I have after seeing that the pointer could've been freed already. But I can't really figure out the whole taxonomy of all these calls to understand what's going on. The average time required to run this and reproduce it is around 12 hours. Rare, but has potential to screw our property-based tests.

Comment: It seems unlikely to me that it is relevant which thread called `mdb_env_open()`.   What I suggested was that the error might arise from `mdb_env_close()` being (previously) called in the same thread that segfaults.  It must be the same thread if you are correct about there being only one MDB-using thread left at the point where `mdb_env_close()` is called.  The theory here would be that `mdb_env_close()` deallocates resources without adequately cleaning up TSD that references those resources.  Again, that would constitute a LMDB bug.

Comment: If that's the case, then one likely workaround would be to use a thread that never performed any LMDB operations to call `mdb_env_close()`, and only after all threads have been joined that actually did perform operations using the environment being closed.  That doesn't have to be the same thread that called `mdb_env_open()`, I wouldn't think, but I can imagine a nice, clean design where it would be.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I see what you're saying. If I understand correctly, you're saying that within the test process, the there might be multiple open/closes of the environment, and the clean up isn't good enough and it's causing the issue. Thank you, I'll be investigating that idea by opening and closing the environment many times and monitoring the memory. Hopefully we'll get somewhere. Cheers!

Comment: No, what I describe does not depend on multiple environments being opened and closed.  I do not anticipate that that would be an issue (though I am postulating a bug in LMDB, so who knows?).  What I describe depends only on the last thread in the group, that being the one to call `mdb_env_close()`, being one that has non-null thread-specific data for the environment in question.  It would have acquired that TSD by previously calling other LMDB functions using the same environment.

Comment: That scenario does require that `mdb_env_close()` fail to delete the relevant TSD key, or else that your pthreads implementation be buggy.  And again, all this is premised on you being right about all the other relevant threads having terminated before `mdb_env_close()` is called.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks for the insights. I'll try that hypothesis. Btw, it's easy to prove that everything is shutdown in order in the test, whose link I provided under your answer. There are two threads and the env is destroyed with RAII upon joining them.

Answer (score 1):

> Are we allowed to call pthread_key_create and pthread_key_delete from different threads?

Yes.

However, a key must be created via `pthread_key_create` before it can be used by any thread, and that is not, itself, inherently thread safe.  The key creation is often synchronized by performing it before starting any (other) threads that will use the key, but there are other alternatives.

Similarly, a key must not be deleted before all threads are finished with it, and the deletion is not, itself, inherently thread safe.  TSD keys often are not deleted at all, and when they are deleted, that is often synchronized by first joining all (other) threads that may use the key.  But again, there are other alternatives.

> The documentation of `pthread_key_create` and `pthread_key_delete` are
> ambiguous to me, personally, in the sense whether they're talking
> about the calls to `pthread_key_create` and `pthread_key_delete` or the
> data underneath the pointers. This is what the docs say:
>
> > The associated destructor functions used to free thread-specific data
> > at thread exit time are only guaranteed to work correctly when called
> > in the thread that allocated the thread-specific data.

The destructor functions those docs are talking about are the ones passed as the second argument to `pthread_key_create()`.

And note well that that text is drawn from the *Rationale* section of the docs, not the *Description* section.  It is talking about **why** the TSD destructor functions are not called by `pthread_key_delete()`, not trying to explain **what** the function does.  That particular point is that TSD destructor functions must run in each thread carrying non-NULL TSD, as opposed to in the thread that calls `pthread_key_delete()`.

> So the question is, can we call `mdb_env_open` and `mdb_env_close` from
> two different threads, leading to `pthread_key_create` and
> `pthread_key_delete` from different threads, and expect correct
> behavior?

The library's use of thread-specific data does not imply otherwise.  However, you seem to be suggesting that there is a race between two different lines in the same function, `mdb_env_close0`, which can be the case only if that function is called in parallel by two different threads.  The [MDB docs](https://manpages.org/mdb/3) say of `mdb_env_close()` that "Only a single thread may call this function."  I would guess that they mean that to be scoped to a particular MDB environment.  In any case, if you really have the race you think you have, then it seems to me that your program must be calling `mdb_env_close()` from multiple threads, contrary to specification.

So, as far as I know or can tell, the thread that calls `mdb_env_close()` does not need to be the same one that called `mdb_env_open()` (or `mdb_env_create()`), but it does need to be the ***only*** one that calls it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm still trying to wrap my head around this. Just a note: It's impossible for `mdb_env_close()` to be called multiple times in our application. It's wrapped in Rust's RAII and is called only with the drop trait (like C++'s RAII), which is in turn called through an Arc (atomic reference counted object) reaching counter value 0. We're not calling this manually: https://github.com/mintlayer/lmdb-rs-mintlayer/blob/bb7d0934edf8be64a6953de71f872906b04a1c79/src/environment.rs#L375

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist, if `mdb_env_close()` is not called from multiple threads, then your guess about a race condition cannot be the explanation for the error you observe.  At least, not that specific race condition.  Conceivably, however, there might still be a race between threads doing other things with the MDB environment and the one that closes it.  Per the docs, all operations involving the environment must be completed before the environment is closed.  Possibly this suggests that your RAII usage is not achieving for you everything you want it to do.

Comment: That's fair. We're still trying to figure out how this is happening. The reason why I don't believe it's a manual attempt to call things after destruction is that the test that fails with this SIGSEGV very rarely joins the threads using lmdb before shutting down. However, we noticed today that the only special thing about this test is that it shuts down lmdb in the thread, unlike the others.  https://github.com/mintlayer/mintlayer-core/blob/a09349cfa7d095eee5211d4278236ef1418c62ae/storage/backend-test-suite/src/concurrent.rs#L125